# If $\phi$ is a solution of $\int_{0}^{x} (1-x^2+t^2)\phi(t)dt=\frac{x^2}{2}$ find $\phi(\sqrt 2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

If $\phi$ is a solution of $$\int_{0}^{x} (1-x^2+t^2)\phi(t)dt=\frac{x^2}{2}$$then find  the value of $\phi(\sqrt 2)$.
Differentiate both side with respect to $x$ (by using Leibniz rule) we have $$\phi(x)=x \implies \phi(\sqrt2)=\sqrt2.$$ But the answer is $\sqrt2 e^2$. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You are not differentiating correctly

Comment: @uniquesolution I think so...but I did it as per the rule. I cannot find any mistake though.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} (1-x^2)\phi(t)dt \neq (1-x^2)\phi(x)$$ Just move $(1-x^2)$ in front of the integral to see the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't differentiate properly. You have to pay extra attention to the $x$ under the integral, you cannot treat it as a constant: it jumps in front and leads to the product rule.

$$\int_{0}^{x} (1-x^2+t^2)\phi(t)dt=\frac{x^2}{2} \\
\int_{0}^{x} (1-x^2)\phi(t)dt+\int_{0}^{x} t^2\phi(t)dt=\frac{x^2}{2}\\
 (1-x^2)\int_{0}^{x}\phi(t)dt+\int_{0}^{x} t^2\phi(t)dt=\frac{x^2}{2} \\
-2x\int_{0}^{x}\phi(t)dt+(1-x^2)\phi(x)+x^2 \phi(x)=x \\
-2x\int_{0}^{x}\phi(t)dt=x- \phi(x) \\
\int_{0}^{x}\phi(t)dt=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{ \phi(x)}{2x} \\
\phi(x)=\frac{\phi'(x)x-\phi(x)}{2x^2} \\2x+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\phi'(x)}{\phi(x)}
$$

Now integrate. Note that by setting $x=0$ in teh fourth equation above you get $$\phi(0)=0$$

Comment: it was easy. but thank you very much.